# keep the output from a post request inside a string variable

Tags: rust

Hi I explain the problem

I'm actually sending a request to the OpenApi and the reply is an url that is basically an image generated by OpenAI.

I would like to keep this url inside a variable after sending a request rather than get this url in the terminal with the println!("{:?}", res);

I need to use this url in an other file after. it's why it's more interesting for me to keep this url in a string variable after the request.

```
use exitfailure::ExitFailure;
use reqwest::{
    header::{ACCEPT, AUTHORIZATION, CONTENT_TYPE},
    Url,
};
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::collections::hash_map::*;
// use std::env;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct GenerationImage {}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Data {
    url: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Response {
    data: [Data; 1],
}

impl GenerationImage {
    async fn post(api_key: &str) -> Result<(), ExitFailure> {
        let key = format!("Bearer {}", api_key);
        let prompt = "a cat behind a tree".to_string();
        let url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations";
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("prompt", prompt);

        let endpoint = Url::parse(url)?;
        let client = reqwest::Client::new();
        let res = client
            .post(endpoint)
            .header(AUTHORIZATION, key)
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
            .json(&map)
            .send()
            .await?
            .json::<Response>()
            .await;
        println!("{:?}", res);
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let api_key = "API";

    GenerationImage::post(&api_key);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert an item that implements `Debug` into the corresponding `String` you can do this:

```rust
let s = format!("{:?}", res);
```